# finding a number in filename using regex

Tags: c#, regex, filenames

I don't have much experience with regexes and I wanted to rectify that. I decided to build an application that takes a directory name, scans all files (that all have a increasing serial number but differ subtly in their filenames. Example : `episode01.mp4`, `episode_02.mp4`, `episod03.mp4`, `episode04.rmvb` etc.)

The application should scan the directory, find the number in each file name and rename the file along wit the extension to a common format (`episode01.mp4`,`episode02.mp4`,`episode03.mp4`,`episode04.rmvb` etc.).

I have the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> renameDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
string newFormat = "Episode{0}.{1}";
Regex regex = new Regex(@".*?(?<no>\d+).*?\.(?<ext>.*)"); //look for a number(before .) aext: *(d+)*.*
foreach (var file in dInfo.GetFiles())
{
  string fileName = file.Name;
  var match = regex.Match(fileName);
  if (match != null)
  {
    GroupCollection gc = match.Groups;
    //Console.WriteLine("Number : {0}, Extension : {2} found  in {1}.", gc["no"], fileName,gc["ext"]);
    renameDictionary[fileName] = string.Format(newFormat, gc["no"], gc["ext"]);
  }
}
foreach (var renamePair in renameDictionary)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} will be renamed to {1}.", renamePair.Key, renamePair.Value);
  //stuff for renaming here
}
```

One problem in this code is that it also includes files which don't have numbers in the `renameDictionary`. It would also be helpful if you could point out any other gotchas that I should be careful about.

PS: I am assuming that the filenames will only contain numbers corresponding to serial (nothing like `cam7_0001.jpg`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simplest solution is probably to use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` to get the file name, and then the regex `\d+$` to get the number at its end (or `Path.GetExtension` and `\d+` to get the number anywhere).

You can also achieve this in a single replace:

```
Regex.Replace(fileName, @".*?(\d+).*(\.[^.]+)$", "Episode$1$2")
```

This regex is a bit better, in that it forces the extension not to contain dots.